# How to fix Apache2 w/ suPHP to scan the correct .ini directory?

Tags: apache2, php

Apache2 was reading the correct area for php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2 until suPHP was added to the system.  Configuring suPHP_ConfigPath in /etc/apache2/mods-available/suphp.conf gets the correct php.ini loaded, but does not correct the directories to be scanned.

How, and where, do I fix this so that Apache loads/scans/uses PHP from the original /etc/php5/apache2 directories?

Edit1:  This has also broken “application/x-httpd-php”, notably localhost/phpmyadmin/ .

Edit2: [Running phpmyadmin and suphp](https://serverfault.com/questions/211935/running-phpmyadmin-and-suphp/806870#806870) solves phpMyAdmin and all others running out of /usr/share/.

====

```
michael@local [~/public_html]# pwd
/home/michael/public_html
michael@local [~/public_html]# alias relub
alias relub='cat /etc/os-release && uname -a'
michael@local [~/public_html]# relub
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
Linux anon 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of phpinfo();

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19

System  Linux anon 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64
Build Date  Jul 28 2016 19:33:50
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/cgi
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-readline.ini
PHP API     20121113
PHP Extension   20121212
Zend Extension  220121212
Zend Extension Build    API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build     API20121212,NTS
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Configuration
bcmath
BCMath support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

bz2
BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

cgi-fcgi
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.discard_path    0   0
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.force_redirect  1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.redirect_status_env no value    no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.logging 1   1

Core
PHP Version     5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,    pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20121212  /usr/lib/php5/20121212
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    512M    512M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value

ctype
ctype functions     enabled

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.35.0
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   Yes
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP     Yes
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1f
ZLib Version    1.2.8

date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    America/Chicago

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value

dba
DBA support     enabled
Supported handlers  cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile

Directive   Local Value Master Value
dba.default_handler flatfile    flatfile

dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.9.1
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled

ereg
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

exif
EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF

Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15

fileinfo
fileinfo support    enabled
version     1.0.5-dev

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 4d3899e089e6e45b157975ceef2ac7deb6e9d762 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support     enabled

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.5.2
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version     8
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.50
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support     enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support     enabled
WebP Support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0

gettext
GetText Support     enabled

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.19

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.3.2
JSON-C version (bundled)    0.11

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version   20901
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation     disabled
libmbfl version     1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check     On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     5.9.2

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.5.52
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.52
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.50
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

pcntl
pcntl support   enabled

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.31 2012-07-06

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.5.52

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: a5488937a80433d434af6753d3db8517feaf91df $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives     enabled
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support     enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

posix
Revision    $Id: 1dfa9997ed76804e53c91e0ce862f3707617b6ed $

readline
Readline Support    enabled
Readline library    EditLine wrapper

Directive   Local Value Master Value
cli.pager   no value    no value
cli.prompt  \b \>   \b \> 

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version     $Id: 31d836a7ac92a37b5c580836d91ad4736fe2f376 $

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  99999   99999
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php5   /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

shmop
shmop support   enabled

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: 363ea1fc44b0b7775e2ec3ce8456530fec6d1660 $
Schema support  enabled

soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

sockets
Sockets Support     enabled

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard
Dynamic Library Support     enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value

sysvmsg
sysvmsg support     enabled
Revision    $Id: adf1d2d6be849c46eed3c3ee6f1cbebd1448d6e5 $

tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx
WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer     enabled

xml
XML Support     active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version     2.9.1

xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled

xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled

Zend OPcache
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup     OK
Shared memory model     mmap
Cache hits  0
Cache misses    1
Used memory     5465856
Free memory     61643008
Wasted memory   0
Cached scripts  1
Cached keys     1
Max keys    3907
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts     0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.load_comments   1   1
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.optimization_level  0xFFFFFFFF  0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On

zip
Zip     enabled
Extension Version   $Id: 05dd1ecc211075107543b0ef8cee488dd229fccf $
Zip version     1.11.0
Libzip version  0.10.1

zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.8
Linked Version  1.2.8

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules
Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment
Variable    Value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/michael/public_html
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/michael/public_html
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
HTTP_CONNECTION     keep-alive
HTTP_DNT    1
HTTP_HOST   localhost
HTTP_REFERER    http://localhost/
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
PATH    /bin:/usr/bin
PHPRC   /etc/php5/apache2
QUERY_STRING    no value
REDIRECT_STATUS     200
REMOTE_ADDR     127.0.0.1
REMOTE_PORT     54226
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
REQUEST_URI     /phpinfo.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME     /home/michael/public_html/phpinfo.php
SCRIPT_NAME     /phpinfo.php
SERVER_ADDR     127.0.0.1
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@localhost
SERVER_NAME     localhost
SERVER_PORT     80
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

PHP Variables
Variable    Value
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/michael/public_html
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/michael/public_html
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.5
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   max-age=0
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_DNT"] 1
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    localhost
_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] http://localhost/
_SERVER["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]   1
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
_SERVER["PATH"] /bin:/usr/bin
_SERVER["PHPRC"]    /etc/php5/apache2
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]  200
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  54226
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /home/michael/public_html/phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@localhost
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  localhost
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /phpinfo.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1475454013.4281
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1475454013
```

Comment: I don't understand your "Edit2". Did that solve the problem or not?

Comment: Hi, Michael.  No, Edit2 only solves Edit1.  e.g. apps installed through Ubuntu into /usr/share/, most notably phpMyAdmin.  I would remove both Edit1 and Edit2, but anyone hitting this will have Edit1’s problems and need the solution in Edit2.  The issue of the question, problem of ‘wrong’ scan path, is still present.